# Error con PHP y MySql (Base de datos)

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, datatables

Estoy ya hace varias horas con esto y no logro resolverlo. Estoy con un proyecto personal, una idea buena, que por no querer que alguien me robe la idea o lo haga otro lo estoy haciendo yo sin haber estudiado ni php ni mysql. Lo peor es que me encanta pero entiendo la mitad de las cosas.

Al grano; intento que un simple formulario me envíe los datos a mi base de datos, pero algo no va bien.. La conexión va bien, fue lo primero que ví, pero debe haber o algo mal en el código o algo mal en mi base de datos, porque o no me llega o no se envian los datos. Adjunto los códigos para ver si alguien ve algo, si no veré de detallar un poco mas.

con_db.php

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","fake_user","fake_pass","mandore2_Alfa");

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
?>
```

index2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registrar usuario</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <h1>¡Materia!</h1>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre completo">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje">
        <input type="submit" name="register">
    </form>
        <?php
        include("registrar.php");
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

registrar.php

```
<?php

include("con_db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['message']) >= 1) {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        $fecha = date("d/m/y");
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO Materia S1(nombre, mensaje, fecha) VALUES ('$name','$message','$fecha')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?>
            <h3 class="ok">¡Enviado!</h3>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
           <?php
        }
    }   else {
            ?>
            <h3 class="bad">¡Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
           <?php
    }
}

?>
```

El error que me sale siempre al llenar los campos y apretar "enviar" es el "bad" que puse aqui arriba; "¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!".

**Actualizo:**

Acabo de ver los error_logs, esto aparece:

```
[17-Sep-2020 04:01:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conex in ...registrar.php on line 11
[17-Sep-2020 04:01:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...registrar.php on line 11
```

La linea 11 de ese archivo sería:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
```

**Actualización 2:**
Ya logré corregir ambos errores reemplazando con_db.php con otro codigo:

```
<?php

$conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","fake_user","fake_pass","mandore2_Alfa");

?>
```

Pero para mi mala suerte me apareció un nuevo error que no le encuentro sentido:

```
[17-Sep-2020 04:17:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /home/.../registrar.php on line 6
```

Esta linea es:

```
  if (strlen($_POST['name']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['message']) >= 1) {
```

Adjunto captura de mi tabla..

[image: PHPMyAdmin]

**Actualizacion 3:**

Arregle lo que vendría siendo el "date" que me dijeron que estaba mal, esa linea quedo asi:

```
   $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

El anterior error no creo que este solucionado o no lo se, pero en error_log ya no aparece ningún error al enviar el formulario, pero aún asi el formulario me sigue dando error..

Comment: Has revisado los logs de php? Lo otro, cuál es el nombre de la tabla donde insertas? Veo un `Materia S1`

Comment: Acabo de revisar los Logs y efectivamente me muestra el error; 
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on ....register.php line 11 - La tabla tiene el nombre de "Materia S1"

Comment: Para poder usar nombres como ese **que emplean caracteres especiales** (en este caso el espacio) debes ponerlo entre las comillas que genera el uso de acentos graves (no me se el nombre) así \`Materia S1\`. Si lo pasas normalmente te generará error.

Comment: Ahí actualice el post con los errores que me salen. Le agregre esas comillas a Materia S1 pero ahora me marca como que debo "rellenar los campos". Error el cual está antes que el que ya me salía.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta cómo está creada la tabla. Puedes usar DESCRIBE o mostrar cómo se ve en phpmyadmin

Comment: Ahí adjunte una imagen de la tabla.

Comment: En la imagen se ve que fecha es de tipo Timestamp y que tiene un predeterminado: el timestamp al momento de insertar el registro. De modo que no necesitas pasar $fecha a la sentencia insert. Adicionalmente `$fecha = date("d/m/y");` **no es de tipo timestamp necesita una conversion**

Comment: Por favor mira [date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) en la documentación de php. Está en español

Comment: Paso a aportar que el tipo de dato Datetime se debe guardar así date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), siempre año, mes y día, en ese orden... aplica igual para el tipo Date.

Comment: Me causa extrañeza que el último error habla de un índice "email", cuando en todos los demás códigos y pantallazo de la DB no hay nada de email. Eso de índice por lo general a mí me sale en arreglos.

Comment: Había en algún momento código referenciando a un campo email? Tiene pinta de que se ha quedado una cache del fichero o no se ha enterado del cambio que has hecho porque en ningún sitio sale ese "email". Normalmente reiniciar el proceso de php/apache etc soluciona ese problema. Pero si estás en windows, carpetas compartidas o algo similar es un problema muy común

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que estas haciendo referencia a $conex aquí:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
```

Pero no tienes esa variable declarada, trata de hacer las cosas con paciencia y siguiendo una lógica (estructurada o en objetos), no te confundas por las prácticas que veas de códigos complejos, haz tu codigo lo más simple posible y ya luego irás mejorando.

Es mi consejo.

***UPDATE***

Veo que le cambiaste el nombre a la variable $mysqli y guardaste su valor en una variable llamada $conex, luego de ahí no veo ningún error. Si se te complica demasiado, trata de hacer el código de nuevo siguiendo mis pautas.

Éxitos y bendiciones